# Putting cross hair over RayCast hit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The following code is used to hit the target. I want to put cross hair (`image` / `object`) over `hit.position`. I have tried to put the same in `Fire()` method, which is executing when i use Fire1 button.

But i want without before pressing Fire1. and the cross hair should move with the camera movement.

**Weapon.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    Collider col;
    Rigidbody rigidBody;
    Animator animator;

    public enum WeaponType
    {
        Pistol, Rifle
    }
    public WeaponType weaponType;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class UserSettings
    {
        public Transform leftHandIKTarget;
        public Vector3 spineRotation;
    }
    [SerializeField]
    public UserSettings userSettings;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class WeaponSettings
    {
        [Header("-Bullet Options-")]
        public Transform bulletSpawn;
        public float damage = 5.0f;
        public float bulletSpread = 5.0f;
        public float fireRate = 0.2f;
        public LayerMask bulletLayers;
        public float range = 200.0f;


        [Header("-Effects-")]
        public GameObject muzzleFlash;
        public GameObject decal;
        public GameObject shell;
        public GameObject clip;

        [Header("-Other-")]
        public float reloadDuration = 2.0f;
        public Transform shellEjectSpot;
        public float shellEjectSpeed = 7.5f;
        public Transform clipEjectPos;
        public GameObject clipGO;

        [Header("-Positioning-")]
        public Vector3 equipPosition;
        public Vector3 equipRotation;
        public Vector3 unequipPosition;
        public Vector3 unequipRotation;

        [Header("-Animation-")]
        public bool useAnimation;
        public int fireAnimationLayer = 0;
        public string fireAnimationName = "Fire";
    }
    [SerializeField]
    public WeaponSettings weaponSettings;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Ammunition
    {
        public int carryingAmmo;
        public int clipAmmo;
        public int maxClipAmmo;
    }
    [SerializeField]
    public Ammunition ammo;

    public Ray shootRay { protected get; set; }

    WeaponHandler owner;
    bool equipped;
    bool pullingTrigger;
    bool resettingCartridge;

    public LineRenderer myLine;
    public GameObject sourceObject;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        col = GetComponent<Collider>();
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        myLine = CreateNewLine (new Vector3[] { Vector3.zero, Vector3.zero });
    }

        // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

       if (owner)
        {
            DisableEnableComponents(false);

            if (equipped)
            {
                if (owner.userSettings.rightHand)
                {
                    Equip();

                    if (pullingTrigger)
                    {
                        Fire(shootRay);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Unequip(weaponType);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            DisableEnableComponents(true);

            transform.SetParent(null);
        }
    }

    //This fires the weapon
    void Fire(Ray ray)
    {
        if (ammo.clipAmmo <= 0 || resettingCartridge || !weaponSettings.bulletSpawn)
            return;

        RaycastHit hit;
        Transform bSpawn = weaponSettings.bulletSpawn;
        Vector3 bSpawnPoint = bSpawn.position;
        Vector3 dir = ray.GetPoint(weaponSettings.range);

       dir += (Vector3)Random.insideUnitCircle * weaponSettings.bulletSpread;

        //Instantiate(sourceObject, bSpawnPoint, Quaternion.identity );

        if(Physics.Raycast(bSpawnPoint, dir, out hit, weaponSettings.range, weaponSettings.bulletLayers))
        {
            #region decal

        //  myLine.SetPosition(0,ray.origin);
        //  myLine.SetPosition(1,hit.point);
        //  myLine.SetColors(Color.red, Color.green);

            Instantiate(sourceObject, hit.point, Quaternion.identity );


            if ((hit.collider.gameObject.isStatic) || !(hit.collider.gameObject.isStatic))
            {
                if (weaponSettings.decal)
                {
                    //Debug.DrawLine(bSpawnPoint, dir, Color.red);
                    Vector3 hitPoint = hit.point;
                    Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal);
                    GameObject decal = Instantiate(weaponSettings.decal, hitPoint, lookRotation) as GameObject;
                    Transform decalT = decal.transform;
                    Transform hitT = hit.transform;
                    decalT.SetParent(hitT);
                    Destroy(decal, Random.Range(30.0f, 45.0f));
                }
            }
            #endregion
        }

        #region muzzle flash
        if (weaponSettings.muzzleFlash)
        {
            Vector3 bulletSpawnPos = weaponSettings.bulletSpawn.position;
            GameObject muzzleFlash = Instantiate(weaponSettings.muzzleFlash, bulletSpawnPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            Transform muzzleT = muzzleFlash.transform;
            muzzleT.SetParent(weaponSettings.bulletSpawn);
            Destroy(muzzleFlash, 1.0f);
        }
        #endregion

        #region shell
        if (weaponSettings.shell)
        {
            if (weaponSettings.shellEjectSpot)
            {
                Vector3 shellEjectPos = weaponSettings.shellEjectSpot.position;
                Quaternion shellEjectRot = weaponSettings.shellEjectSpot.rotation;
                GameObject shell = Instantiate(weaponSettings.shell, shellEjectPos, shellEjectRot) as GameObject;

                if (shell.GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
                {
                    Rigidbody rigidB = shell.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                    rigidB.AddForce(weaponSettings.shellEjectSpot.forward * weaponSettings.shellEjectSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
                }

                Destroy(shell, Random.Range(30.0f, 45.0f));
            }
        }
        #endregion

        if (weaponSettings.useAnimation)
            animator.Play(weaponSettings.fireAnimationName, weaponSettings.fireAnimationLayer);

        ammo.clipAmmo--;
        resettingCartridge = true;
        StartCoroutine(LoadNextBullet());
    }

    //Loads the next bullet into the chamber
    IEnumerator LoadNextBullet()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(weaponSettings.fireRate);
        resettingCartridge = false;
    }

    //Disables or enables collider and rigidbody
    void DisableEnableComponents(bool enabled)
    {
        if(!enabled)
        {
            rigidBody.isKinematic = true;
            col.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            rigidBody.isKinematic = false;
            col.enabled = true;
        }
    }

    //Equips this weapon to the hand
    void Equip()
    {
        if (!owner)
            return;
        else if (!owner.userSettings.rightHand)
            return;

        transform.SetParent(owner.userSettings.rightHand);
        transform.localPosition = weaponSettings.equipPosition;
        Quaternion equipRot = Quaternion.Euler(weaponSettings.equipRotation);
        transform.localRotation = equipRot;
    }

    //Unequips the weapon and places it to the desired location
    void Unequip(WeaponType wpType)
    {
        if (!owner)
            return;

        switch (wpType)
        {
            case WeaponType.Pistol:
                transform.SetParent(owner.userSettings.pistolUnequipSpot);
                break;
            case WeaponType.Rifle:
                transform.SetParent(owner.userSettings.rifleUnequipSpot);
                break;
        }
        transform.localPosition = weaponSettings.unequipPosition;
        Quaternion unEquipRot = Quaternion.Euler(weaponSettings.unequipRotation);
        transform.localRotation = unEquipRot;
    }

    //Loads the clip and calculates the ammo
    public void LoadClip()
    {
        int ammoNeeded = ammo.maxClipAmmo - ammo.clipAmmo;

        if(ammoNeeded >= ammo.carryingAmmo)
        {
            ammo.clipAmmo = ammo.carryingAmmo;
            ammo.carryingAmmo = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ammo.carryingAmmo -= ammoNeeded;
            ammo.clipAmmo = ammo.maxClipAmmo;
        }
    }

    //Sets the weapons equip state
    public void SetEquipped(bool equip)
    {
        equipped = equip;
    }

    //Pulls the trigger
    public void PullTrigger(bool isPulling)
    {
        pullingTrigger = isPulling;
    }

    //Sets the owner of this weapon
    public void SetOwner(WeaponHandler wp)
    {
        owner = wp;
    }

    //Create a new Line render and sets up the first two points
    public LineRenderer CreateNewLine(Vector3[] points) {
        //Create the GameOBject and name it
        GameObject go = new GameObject();
        go.name = "MyLineRenderer";

        //Add a lien renderer to the gameObject and store its isntance as "line"
        var line = go.AddComponent<LineRenderer>() as LineRenderer;

        //Set the number of points
        line.SetVertexCount(2);

        //Use world space
        line.useWorldSpace = true;

        //Sets the positions of the first two points
        line.SetPosition(0,points[0]);
        line.SetPosition(1,points[1]);
        return line;
    }
}
```

Here is **CameraRig.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class CameraRig : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public bool autoTargetPlayer;
    public LayerMask wallLayers;

    public enum Shoulder
    {
        Right, Left
    }
    public Shoulder shoulder;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class CameraSettings
    {
        [Header("-Positioning-")]
        public Vector3 camPositionOffsetLeft;
        public Vector3 camPositionOffsetRight;

        [Header("-Camera Options-")]
        public float mouseXSensitivity = 5.0f;
        public float mouseYSensitivity = 5.0f;
        public float minAngle = -30.0f;
        public float maxAngle = 70.0f;
        public float rotationSpeed = 5.0f;
        public float maxCheckDist = 0.1f;

        [Header("-Zoom-")]
        public float fieldOfView = 70.0f;
        public float zoomFieldOfView = 30.0f;
        public float zoomSpeed = 3.0f;

        [Header("-Visual Options-")]
        public float hideMeshWhenDistance = 0.5f;
    }
    [SerializeField]
    public CameraSettings cameraSettings;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class InputSettings
    {
        public string verticalAxis = "Mouse X";
        public string horizontalAxis = "Mouse Y";
        public string aimButton = "Fire2";
        public string switchShoulderButton = "Fire4";
    }
    [SerializeField]
    public InputSettings input;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class MovementSettings
    {
        public float movementLerpSpeed = 5.0f;
    }
    [SerializeField]
    public MovementSettings movement;

    Transform pivot;
    Camera mainCamera;
    float newX = 0.0f;
    float newY = 0.0f;


    public GameObject sourceObject;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
        pivot = transform.GetChild(0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (target)
        {
            if (Application.isPlaying)
            {
                RotateCamera();
                CheckWall();
                CheckMeshRenderer();
                Zoom(Input.GetButton(input.aimButton));

                if (Input.GetButtonDown(input.switchShoulderButton))
                {
                    SwitchShoulders();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (!target)
        {
            TargetPlayer();
        }
        else
        {
            Vector3 targetPostion = target.position;
            Quaternion targetRotation = target.rotation;

            FollowTarget(targetPostion, targetRotation);
        }
    }

    //Finds the plater gameObject and sets it as target
    void TargetPlayer()
    {
        if (autoTargetPlayer)
        {
            GameObject player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");

            if (player)
            {
                Transform playerT = player.transform;
                target = playerT;
            }
        }
    }

    //Following the target with Time.deltaTime smoothly
    void FollowTarget(Vector3 targetPosition, Quaternion targetRotation)
    {
        if (!Application.isPlaying)
        {
            transform.position = targetPosition;
            transform.rotation = targetRotation;
        }
        else
        {
            Vector3 newPos = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * movement.movementLerpSpeed);
            transform.position = newPos;
        }
    }

    //Rotates the camera with input
    void RotateCamera()
    {
        if (!pivot)
            return;

        newX += cameraSettings.mouseXSensitivity * Input.GetAxis(input.verticalAxis);
        newY += cameraSettings.mouseYSensitivity * Input.GetAxis(input.horizontalAxis);

        Vector3 eulerAngleAxis = new Vector3();
        eulerAngleAxis.x = newY;
        eulerAngleAxis.y = newX;

        newX = Mathf.Repeat(newX, 360);
        newY = Mathf.Clamp(newY, cameraSettings.minAngle, cameraSettings.maxAngle);

        Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(pivot.localRotation, Quaternion.Euler(eulerAngleAxis), Time.deltaTime * cameraSettings.rotationSpeed);

        pivot.localRotation = newRotation;
    }

    //Checks the wall and moves the camera up if we hit
    void CheckWall()
    {
        if (!pivot || !mainCamera)
            return;

        RaycastHit hit;

        Transform mainCamT = mainCamera.transform;
        Vector3 mainCamPos = mainCamT.position;
        Vector3 pivotPos = pivot.position;

        Vector3 start = pivotPos;
        Vector3 dir = mainCamPos - pivotPos;

        float dist = Mathf.Abs(shoulder == Shoulder.Left ? cameraSettings.camPositionOffsetLeft.z : cameraSettings.camPositionOffsetRight.z);

        if(Physics.SphereCast(start, cameraSettings.maxCheckDist, dir, out hit, dist, wallLayers))
        {
            MoveCamUp(hit, pivotPos, dir, mainCamT);
        }
        else
        {
            switch (shoulder)
            {
                case Shoulder.Left:
                    PostionCamera(cameraSettings.camPositionOffsetLeft);
                    break;
                case Shoulder.Right:
                    PostionCamera(cameraSettings.camPositionOffsetRight);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    //This moves the camera forward when we hit a wall
    void MoveCamUp(RaycastHit hit, Vector3 pivotPos, Vector3 dir, Transform cameraT)
    {
        float hitDist = hit.distance;
        Vector3 sphereCastCenter = pivotPos + (dir.normalized * hitDist);
        cameraT.position = sphereCastCenter;
        //
    }

    //Postions the cameras localPosition to a given location
    void PostionCamera(Vector3 cameraPos)
    {
        if (!mainCamera)
            return;

        Transform mainCamT = mainCamera.transform;
        Vector3 mainCamPos = mainCamT.localPosition;
        Vector3 newPos = Vector3.Lerp(mainCamPos, cameraPos, Time.deltaTime * movement.movementLerpSpeed);
        mainCamT.localPosition = newPos;
    }

    //Hides the mesh targets mesh renderers when too close
    void CheckMeshRenderer()
    {
        if (!mainCamera || !target)
            return;

        SkinnedMeshRenderer[] meshes = target.GetComponentsInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
        Transform mainCamT = mainCamera.transform;
        Vector3 mainCamPos = mainCamT.position;
        Vector3 targetPos = target.position;
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(mainCamPos, (targetPos + target.up));




        if(meshes.Length > 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < meshes.Length; i++)
            {
                if(dist <= cameraSettings.hideMeshWhenDistance)
                {
                    meshes[i].enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    meshes[i].enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Zooms the camera in and out
    void Zoom(bool isZooming)
    {
        if (!mainCamera)
            return;

        if (isZooming)
        {
            float newFieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(mainCamera.fieldOfView, cameraSettings.zoomFieldOfView, Time.deltaTime * cameraSettings.zoomSpeed);
            mainCamera.fieldOfView = newFieldOfView;
        }
        else
        {
            float originalFieldOfView = Mathf.Lerp(mainCamera.fieldOfView, cameraSettings.fieldOfView, Time.deltaTime * cameraSettings.zoomSpeed);
            mainCamera.fieldOfView = originalFieldOfView;
        }
    }

    //Switches the cameras shoulder view
    public void SwitchShoulders()
    {
        switch (shoulder)
        {
            case Shoulder.Left:
                shoulder = Shoulder.Right;
                break;
            case Shoulder.Right:
                shoulder = Shoulder.Left;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

trying since yesterday, not able to get it.. tried to put LineRendered which works perfectly, but the same after pressing Fire1. i want before Fire1..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When the enemy receives a hit, send a message to the player that the event has occurred.

When the player receives that message, render a crosshair on the screen in the same way you rendered the original.

Comment: true, but the enemy is receiving hit if i press Fire1 button, but i want all this before I press Fire1, As the raycast is in Fire() method, which is executing if i press Fire1 button. Please help where should i add code for cross hair, probably in update(), but in update() method, there is no RayCast, so where ???

Comment: @GaganAhuja "There's no raycast method." Uh, yeah there is. `Physics.RayCast`.  You can use it anywhere.

Comment: @GaganAhuja, you could always just have a 'permanent' raycast, so you always know where they player is looking. You can then either have that raycast send the player a message or have the enemy send a message when it's contacted by that raycast, so the player then draws the crosshair.

You could probably use this elsewhere and whether the enemy or the raycast sends the message is dependant on where you want to put code for the player seeing things.